# Verification of MIPS Assembly Code for Memory-Mapped I/O

Tags: c, mips32, memory-mapped-io

I am seeking assistance from the community to verify the correctness of a MIPS assembly code that I have written to translate a C code involving memory-mapped I/O operations. The C code includes the manipulation of volatile pointers, bitwise operations, and memory access. I want to ensure that the MIPS assembly code accurately captures the intended functionality without errors.

```
# volatile int* leds = (volatile int*) 0x1dbb8050;
lui $t0, 0x1dbb
ori $t0, $t0, 0x8050

# volatile int* switches = (volatile int*) 0x22430030;
lui $t1, 0x2243
ori $t1, $t1, 0x0030

# int temp = *leds & 0xff9f
lw $t2, 0($t0)
andi $t2, $t2, 0xff9f

# *leds = ((((*switches) >> 4) & 0x3));
lw $t0, 0($t1)
srl $t0, $t0, 4
andi $t0, $t0, 0x3

# *leds = temp | (switches >> 4 & 0x3) << 3;
sll $t0, $t0, 3
or $t0, $t0, $t2
sw $t0, 0($t0)
```

And here's the full C code:

```
volatile int* leds = (volatile int*) 0x1dbb8050;
volatile int* switches = (volatile int*) 0x22430030;
*leds = (*leds & 0xff9f) | ((((*switches) >> 4) & 0x3) << 3);
```

I have translated the C code into MIPS assembly, taking care to handle volatile pointers, bitwise operations, and memory access correctly. I expected the MIPS code to faithfully represent the behavior of the original C code, ensuring that the memory-mapped I/O operations are accurately performed.

Comment: Did you compare your presumably hand-written assembly to the output of a compiler? Did you try your code, what is the result? A simple test run should show.